# JQuery `.blur()` in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JQuery, I can [use `.blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) on an element:

```js
$('x').blur();
```

Is this the correct way to replace the `blur()` call in vanilla JS?

```js
document.querySelector('x').dispatchEvent('blur');
```

Comment: No. You need to create an Event object and provide that to `dispatchEvent`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You are right! Feel free to post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it simply by using event name as method call. Use `blur()` on the selector to trigger the event,

```js
document.querySelector('x').blur();
// or 
document.getElementById('x').blur();
```

**other events**

```
.click()
.focus()
.submit()
```

[Refer More Events Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)

---

**dispatchEvent**

The `dispatchEvent` method commonly use to trigger a custom event.

```js
var myEvent = new Event('myEvent');

// Listen for the event.
document.querySelector('x').addEventListener('myEvent', function (e) { /* ... */ }, false);

// Dispatch the event.
document.querySelector('x').dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 2):

in case of listeners please use next

```
document.querySelector('x').addEventListener('blur', yourFunction);
```

to trigger an event

```
document.querySelector('x').blur();
```